# XQuartz is not starting from within tmux

Tags: macos, terminal, x11, zsh, tmux

I'm using the standard apple terminal with `zsh` as my default shell.

In my `~/.zprofile` (equivalent of `.profile`) I have the following line:

```
[[ $TERM != "screen" ]] && exec tmux
```

This basically makes shure that if I open a new window in `zsh` a new
`tmux` session is started, but `tmux` doesn't get started from within `zsh`
sessions running inside `tmux` subwindows.

This works fine but for one thing: I cannot start XQuartz. Everytime I launch an from the command line that requires X11 (like a `gnuplot` or `octave` plot) the terminal just hangs and nothing happens.

However, I noticed that when I just disable the auto-launching of `tmux` by removing the line above so that I can open a new terminal window and launch XQuartz from there, I can also use the launched XQuartz from within `tmux` windows.

This however gets pretty tiresome.

How could I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving [[ $TERM != "screen" ]] && exec tmux to your .zshrc file. That way the command will only be run in interactive shells.

An interactive shell is simply any shell process that you use to type commands, and get back output from those commands. That is, a shell with which you interact.